# Collapse group doesn't work in multilevel expandable list view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a multi level `ExpandableListView`. I need to expand only one item at a time. In the second level, I've used this method but it didn't work:

```
simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastExpandedPositions != -1 && groupPosition != lastExpandedPositions) {
            simpleExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPositions);
            // getChildView
        }
        lastExpandedPositions = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Why doesn't the method `collapseGroup(lastExpandedPositions)` response?
could any one help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved and  the  answer is in the code below I added this code  into getchildView() method in   first level expandable list adapter:

```
int  lastExpandedPositions=-1;

simpleExpandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view,
                                            int groupPosition, long id) {

                    setListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);

                       parent.smoothScrollToPosition(groupPosition);

                    // Need default behaviour here otherwise group does not get expanded/collapsed
                    if (parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)) {
                        parent.collapseGroup(groupPosition);

                    } else {
                        parent.expandGroup(groupPosition);
                        if (lastExpandedPositions != -1
                                && groupPosition != lastExpandedPositions) {
                          parent.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPositions);



                        }
                        lastExpandedPositions = groupPosition;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
```